# How to call static function from constructor in same class PHP?

Tags: php, function, static, constructor

Hello i would like to ask:
How to call static function from constructor in same class PHP?

I have got:

```
public function __construct()
```

And I need to call this function

```
private function _regenerateThumbnails($type = 'all', $deleteOldImages = false)
```

in constructor.

Is it possible in PHP and if yes, how?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, you should explicitly declare that method static, like this:

```
private static function _regenerateThumbnails($type = 'all', $deleteOldImages = false)
```

To call it in your constructor, use the `self` keyword:

```
public function __construct() {
    // Pass arguments from your constructor to your method
    // where appropriate
    self::_regenerateThumbnails();
}
```